# not all arguments converted during string formatting - reading csv, tuples iteration, writing into database

Tags: python, tuples, pymysql

I'm still a beginner and I stuck on this problem for some time.
I am trying to recreate this https://datatofish.com/import-csv-sql-server-python/ but with more columns, and even more rows.

Data set is from https://www.kaggle.com/anikannal/solar-power-generation-data -->
Plant_1_Generation_Data.csv

What is the idea of this program? - To read random data set in CSV format and insert those data into my SQL database.

The database connection is ok.
A table was successfully created and is visible in the database.

The code is bellow. Note that I commented 'create table' query since the table is already created.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

'''defining attributes and csv reading'''

data = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Programiranje\csv_practice\Plants data\Plant_1_Generation_Data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['DATE_TIME', 'PLANT_ID', 'SOURCE_KEY', 'DC_POWER', 'AC_POWER', 
'DAILY_YIELD','TOTAL_YIELD'])

'''database connection and table creation'''

 cnx = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='ivan', password='XXX', db='plants_data')
 cursor = cnx.cursor()
 '''cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE plant_data(DATE_TIME datetime, PLANT_ID int, SOURCE_KEY 
 varchar(255), DC_POWER real,AC_POWER real, DAILY_YIELD real, TOTAL_YIELD real)')'''

 '''touple iteration and writing into the table'''

for row in df.itertuples():
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO plants_data.dbo.plant_data(DATE_TIME,PLANT_ID,SOURCE_KEY,DC_POWER,AC_POWER,DAILY_YIELD,TOTAL_YIELD)
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ''',
    (row.DATE_TIME,
     row.PLANT_ID,
     row.SOURCE_KEY,
     row.DC_POWER,
     row.AC_POWER,
     row.DAILY_YIELD,
     row.TOTAL_YIELD,)
)
cnx.commit()
```

and Error is

```
    E:\Programiranje\csv_practice\Scripts\python.exe E:/Programiranje/Python/csv_practice/main.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:/Programiranje/Python/csv_practice/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    cursor.execute(
    File "E:\Programiranje\csv_practice\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 161, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
    File "E:\Programiranje\csv_practice\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 140, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

I believe that error is related to data types - I think that he is confused with strings - but I simply don't understand what should I change. I've tried with %s instead of '?', but that resulted in even more errors.

Also, I would like to mention that I received an error saying "TypeError: execute() takes 2 or 3 arguments 9 given" which I eventually fixed with adding the brackets in the part

```
(row.DATE_TIME,
 row.PLANT_ID,
 row.SOURCE_KEY,
 row.DC_POWER,
 row.AC_POWER,
 row.DAILY_YIELD,
 row.TOTAL_YIELD,)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The default placeholder used by a DB-API connector is defined by the value of the connector module's [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) attribute.  In the case of `pymysql`,

```
>>> pymysql.paramstyle
'pyformat'
```

which means that `pymysql` expects `"%s"` as the placeholder, not `"?"`.  The style `"%(name)s"` may also be used if a mapping of the values is passed rather than a tuple.

So the query should be

```
'''INSERT INTO plants_data.dbo.plant_data(DATE_TIME,PLANT_ID,SOURCE_KEY,DC_POWER,AC_POWER,DAILY_YIELD,TOTAL_YIELD)
    VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
```

Comment: thank you, this helped, I've managed to insert the data into the database. I've tried the same thing before and it didn't work o.O. Anyway, I also removed `dbo` part in the INSERT query, and altered the table and DATE_TIME column since it gave some weird error due to date and time format in the dataset...